# “No video with supported format and mime type found”

Tags: python, django, html, macos, firefox

I am working with django 1.6, python 2.7, firefox 30 and Mac OS 10.10 Beta. When I render the following code

```
<video width="570" height="340" controls="controls">
    <source src="/some/path/"  type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

I get an error on FF stating **"No video with supported format and mime type found"**. The same code runs perfectly on Safari and Chrome (yes I still haven't checked IE).

I have tried different formats for the uploaded files and looked into ad-ons which might prevent this or different coding mechanisms, though nothing has been helpful. Please help!!!!

[image]

Comment: Check MIME type of your server.

Comment: @Zain Khan Did you get your solution?